# Web service RESTFUL or JSP

Tags: java, web-services, url

I was asked to make a web application which should be able to order some words. For example, colors.

I think the best way is to send colors by url and send that url (url.php?listColors...) to the server (and server orders them).

Or send them by json file and return a json file with colors ordered.

But I was asked also to do it with a restul service. I have read something about them and I think it would be a little bit difficult because I just find info about get or post resources. But nothing about send a list of "things" and make something with that. I should make web service in java.

I think it is too heavy if I have to include all words in the web service.

With JSP I can send all words and make a method for ordering them...

What do you think? I would want to have other opinion and ideas to make it the best way possible.

Answer (score 4):

Restful web services and JSP are two sides of the same coin. You use JSP when the client is typically a web browser which needs to display the contents in HTML. You use Restful WS when the client is some other application which needs data. The other application can be a javascript in browser.

Restful support all the data ( via GET/POST/PUT) including list of items etc. So this should not be the criteria of selecting whether to use JSP or Restful.

To answer your other question, as I mentioned, you could use either of Restful or JSP. It depends whats the use case is.

Comment: Thanks, then I will try to do with a web service as I was asked.

Answer (score 1):

RESTful handles all object types so you could just make a method like:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<String> orderWords(List<String> words);
```

If you have a performance criteria just use the gzip compression.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will write down what you wrote to check when I finish to read info about web services

Comment: I am trying to make a simple example to check if it works. But I got asome exceptions from my tomcat server. If I use @GET for typical hello word, etc it works fine without client. But, I tried your code (just with int returns) and I used Ajax client to check in webpage:
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Matriz/rest/hello',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) { alert(data); }
});

I changed your code this way: 
public int orderWords(){
  int cinco = 5;
  return cinco;
}

But if I check tomcat in eclipse, I got some exceptions this time....

Comment: hmmm, it would be nice to see your exceptions. :-)